# PHP JQuery Ajax Inline Editing with select option

Tags: php, jquery, sql-server, ajax, inline

I'm using a php jquery ajax inline editing system which works the way it's supposed to until I add in a select option list. Below is the jquery and php/html layout from the project I'm working on, every saves to the DB properly with the exception of the select option no matter what I've tried.

```
<script>
function showEdit(editableObj) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF");
} 

function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) {
    $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
    $.ajax({
        url: "update_door_schedule.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
        success: function(data){
            $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
        }        
    });
}
```

```
<td class="left" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'[Date and Time Entered]','<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $schedule_row['Date and Time Entered']; ?></td>
        <td class="left" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'[Door Number]','<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $schedule_row['Door Number']; ?></td>
        <td class="left" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'[Customer Xref]','<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $schedule_row['Customer Xref']; ?></td>
        <td class="left" contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'[Interior or Exterior]','<?php echo $schedule_row['id']; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);">
            <select class="input-clearfit">
                <?php if($schedule_row['Interior or Exterior'] > ' '){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $schedule_row['Interior or Exterior']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $schedule_row['Interior or Exterior']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>  
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT Product, [Sort Sequence]
                FROM DD_Product
                ORDER BY [Sort Sequence]"); 
                while ($list_row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $list_row['Product']; ?>"><?php echo $list_row['Product']; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>     
            </select>
        </td>
```

Comment: What happens? Doesn't get saved at all? Checked the database? Checked your log files? Wrong data gets saved? Error messages? More details, please...

Comment: everything saves to the DB but nothing changes when a select option is selected.

Comment: I don't see any events for the actual selectbox? What is suppose to happen?

Comment: when the option is selected it should trigger the onBlur event to saveToDatabase ... the preceeding td's all post to the db on change. I've tried moving the onblur and onclick's to the select and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Selecting an option doesn't trigger onBlur. test: `onchange` on the selectbox instead.

Comment: That doesn't work either, no errors, no log file entries and no change to the db record.

Answer (score 0):

After several different variations and a lot of googling the answer was right in front of me ...

Replace innerhtml() with val() and place input fields and/or select option menus within the td's.